# How do I unlock the swordsmanship, alchemy and magic paths?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I'm already at character level 5, but when I look at the character abilities page, the three trees for swordsmanship, alchemy and magic are still locked. I can only invest talents into the training tree.

Do I have to get to a certain point in the story to unlock them? Or am I missing something obvious.

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the manual:

> **4.3 Development paths**
>
> **Training** – the primary development path. To begin another path, you must spend at
> least **six talents** on the talent path abilities..

Answer (score 7):

I now found a section in the in-game help that states that you need to invest 6 talents into the witcher tree before the other three trees are unlocked. When I reached character level 7 and invested the 6 talents, it did indeed unlock the other trees.